# Why does JSON.parse does not work with this string?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I can't parse the following string:

```js
try {
  var data_obj = JSON.parse("{'raw': -243666272256, 'format': '-24.67BB', 'longFormat': '-243,666,272M'}")
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
cnsole.log(data_obj.raw)
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to, no; that's **not** JSON. Where's it coming from?

Comment: I've added a snippet and wrapped the code in a `try/catch` to show the error.

Comment: JSON requires that strings be ***double quoted*** (i.e. enclosed in `"`)...

Comment: how is that not JSON?

Comment: It's because the strings are not double quoted. Refer to the official spec [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)...

Comment: Where are you retrieving the data from? Is it a webservice, file, hardcoded, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

JSON standard does not allow single quotation when you wrap your property and do not parse it. Instead, It expects double quotation. Please  check the below example:

```
var data_obj = JSON.parse('{"raw":-243666272256,"format":"-24.67BB","longFormat":"-243,666,272M"}');
        console.log(data_obj, 'data');
        console.log(data_obj.raw);
```

Comment: why console.log(data_obj, 'data'); ?

Comment: @khabir You should explain what your answer does differently instead of just posting a block of code. The *why* is much more important in the long run than the *how*.

Comment: I just print data_obj in console and 'data' is just a label

Comment: @BrianThompson, Thank you. I added the description